# Validar nome do método, sugerindo o correto

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes, método

Eu estou utilizando uma classe da biblioteca de email do framework [Nette](https://github.com/nette/mail).

Daí em algum momento, ao invés de chamar o método `setSubject` - que é o método correto, chamei `addSubject`, pois tinha esquecido o nome do método.

Logo, foi me retornado o seguinte erro:

> Method addSubject does not exists. Did you mean setSubject?

Ou seja, ele sugeriu que o nome correto do método da classe fosse `setSubject`.

Como posso fazer isso em uma (ou várias) classes minhas em PHP?

Exemplo:

```
class Myclass
{
    public function callMethod()
    {
    }
}


(new MyClass)->callMyMethod(); // Lança a exceção sugerindo o nome correto
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [Magic Methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php)

Esta deve ser uma implementação do método mágico **__call**.

> __call () é acionado quando são invocados métodos inacessíveis em um objeto.

#### Exemplo

```
class MyClass{

    private $methods = array(
        'runTest' => array(
            'run',
            'RunTest',
            'runstest',
            'runMyTest',
        ),
    );

    public function __call($name, $args){

        $realName = null;
        foreach ($this->methods as $method => $alias){
            foreach ($alias as $k => $wrong){
                if(preg_match("~{$wrong}~i", $name)){
                    $realName = $method;
                    break 2;
                }
            }
        }

        echo "Method {$name} does not exists.";
        if(!empty($realName)){
            echo " Did you mean {$realName}?";
        }
    }

    public function runTest(){
        echo 'HERE';
    }
}

$obj = new MyClass;
$obj->run('in object context'); // Method run does not exists. Did you mean runTest?
$obj->runTest('in object context'); // HERE
```

Comment: +1 legal. Creio que seja por aí mesmo :)